# Will Ubuntu 12 run on my Lenovo Z570

Tags: intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I read somewhere that the graphics were sluggy because of graphic Card !

SPECS OF MY LENOVO:

Graphics:

- Nvidia GT-520m (1GB)
- Intel HD Graphics (1GB)

pls do tell me!